# netctl profile ignored on reboot of Arch Linux VirtualBox VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, arch-linux

I setup a netctl profile for a network device enp0s8. The profile gives a static IP address to the interface. If I turn down the existing profile for the device (automatically setup at boot) and start my profile for the device, the device correctly gets the static IP address. However, when I reboot the machine, my profile defined in /etc/netctl/enp0s8 for that interface is ignored although I enabled if (`netctl enable enp0s8`)

What am I doing wrong? From where is Arch Linux getting its network configuration profiles?

Thanks

Comment: Is the netctl service enabled at boot? Netctl-enabled profiles will only run if the netctl service itself is enabled by systemd.